# Type of id function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In GHCI, the type of `id` is:

```
Prelude> :t id
id :: a -> a
```

But if I define my own `id` function, why is the name of the type variable `t` ? Is there a difference between `t` and `a` ?

```
Prelude> let identity x = x
Prelude> :t identity
identity :: t -> t
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference between `a` and `t`, they are called Type variables and stand for any type you can have. Note that they are written in lowercase letters where types are written with an uppercase letter at the beginning (except for lists, who have special syntax).

In addition if you write a file and load it into ghci by `ghci testmodule.hs`

```
module Testmodule where

identity :: b -> b
identity x = x
```

then ghci will show you exactly the letter you used in your definition.

Comment: The important part is that t -> t the type stays the same. Which is the wanted the behavior of the id function

Comment: Also I find it helpful to mentally substitute `id :: a -> a` with `id :: forall a. a -> a`. This way it's clear where the type variable is bound(declared).

Answer (score 6):

This has actually the same answer as if I were asking

> If I define my own version of your version as
>
> `Prelude> let identity' q = q`
> why is the name of the value variable `q`? Is there a difference between `q` and `x`?

The crucial thing about parameter variables in general is that their names are basically *arbitrary*. It's a fundamental property of lambda-calculus: [α-equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence). We merely replace `\x -> x` with `\q -> q` (or, in lambda-style, `λx.x` with `λq.q`). And indeed type variables are parameters as well, though it doesn't really look like they are. But under the hood, Haskell polymorphic signatures should be read as [System F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F), so really we have `Λα . α -> α`, usually written `forall a . a -> a`. Which is obviously equivalent to `forall t . t -> t`.

Comment: The identity q = q affecting the type variable name is false. The type variable name is unrelated to the variable names used in the definition.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea He doesn't say or imply that anywhere in this answer.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea: indeed; please read properly! (Admittedly, the lack of extra color backing of code snippets within quotes doesn't help things (I reformatted it to make the intention a bit clearer), but I still can't see how you could mistake this to say anything about interactions between the type- and value-level scopes.)

Comment: The reword/reformat makes a big difference. Vote amended :)

Comment: I just reviewed the diff. You clearly said *value* variable, which was correct as it was. Not my best work.